# Different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a question:
In spring mvc using hibernate(session hibernate) I get object1, and right after that I want to get a list of objects which is the previously obiek1, and I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same 
identifier value was already associated with the session...
```

how to merg this object in one session?
My code to get list:

```
    Criteria crit = session.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Object1.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("status", 1));
    return crit.list();
```

I must open new session to get list?

Answer (score 0):

@kuka11 : Using `session.merge(object)` would be usefull. Read [this](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/12/07/saveorupdate-versus-merge-in-hibernate/) article.